# Upgrade Access Tier via Azure CLI or Python Code for Storage Account Gen2

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, azure-data-lake, azure-data-lake-gen2

We Want to update the access tiers in the ADLS Gen2 for Multiple paths and want to use Azure CLI or Python Code as per our requirement.
According to Microsoft Documentation, We see only Portal and Power shell code to do it.
Can anyone let us know if we can explore through the mentioned code.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this command -

```
az storage account update -g <resource-group> -n <storage-account> --set kind=StorageV2 --access-tier=<Hot/Cool>
```

I was able to update the access tier of Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2 using this command.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you want to change account access tier or blob access tier.
If you want to change blob access tier.
You can try this command:

```
az storage blob set-tier --account-key 00000000 --account-name MyAccount --container-name MyContainer --name MyBlob --tier Hot
```

tier value choose among Archive, Cool, Hot.

Below is my test screenshot,it works:
[image]

Here is the [API document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/storage/blob?view=azure-cli-latest#az-storage-blob-set-tier).

Comment: Thanks, Steve, what will be the command if I want to change all blobs access tier?